# Use mobile phone gpu to mine

Tags: mining, gpu

Is it possible to use several mobile phone GPU to mine Ethereum? 
Advantages are

- Less power consumption and
- No fan and robust material

Mobile phones do not have much memory, but if a manufacturer like Qualcomm made one just for mining will this run or not? Is this a good idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "robust material"?

Comment: Something that is design to run 24h for a day.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unintelligible.ethafflicted What do you think of this app?

Answer (score 3):

No. This is not possible, nor is it a good idea.

Individual computers are often not powerful enough to mine Ethereum blocks.
This is why people mine in pools (for example [nanopool](https://eth.nanopool.org/))

Mobile phones have significantly less powerful processors (and graphics units) so as to keep costs down.

Comment: Just to add, if Qualcomm made a phone designed for mining, it would just be a desktop pc with graphics cards and the ability to place phone calls.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, read up on the scratchpad cache requirements for mining cryptonote algorithms... It's rough. Various other methods exist using other code and  platforms to allow any task done in the technical papers on alternative platforms, but if requires a lot of work around and so far, no one has to my knowledge spent the time to write it. I'd love to see Snapdragon and similar mining options as well as make use of limited architecture of mobile GPU. The technical papers breaks down each step in the mining process and cryptographic setup. Unloading some of the work in a cross platform to make use of CPU cycles and GPU cycles both would be interesting to work on... If anyone wants to start the project I'll join and work on it for fun but realize there's no real world case I can see where it'll work with the current code base without significant forking from their intended use case...

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@bitwings/wings-mobile-the-future-of-smartphones-and-cryptocurrency-5e8783619545

They say they have a revolutionary mining cellphone !